# Access windows application installed in EC2 using browser

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, browser

I have installed QAD Netui Client (application with .exe executable) on Windows EC2 instance.
I would like to access that application through web browser or by any other way without the need of logging-in into windows instance.

The reason behind this requirement is that, I don't want users to get information about machine on which my application is installed.

Is there any way to achieve this requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

Not likely. This appears to be a Window GUI application rather than something like a web application.

As a GUI application it needs a Windows desktop session to run. This is accomplished with remote desktop or other similar application that allows you to share a desktop with another client.

However, you can set up a Windows user profile that has much more restricted access to the machine. This is probably the closest you will get.